# remove folders remotely except some with powershell

Tags: powershell

I have to delete the user profile folders from some pc, except the Administrator folder. The script I'm using is the following:

```
    $Computerlist = get-content C:\windows\temp\pc.txt 
Foreach ($computer in $Computerlist) 
{Get–ChildItem –Path \\$computer\c$\users\*.* –Include *.*  –Force | Where-Object $_.Name -notmatch "Administrator" | Remove-Item -Force -Recurse
}
```

but it return the following error:

```
Where-Object : Impossibile convalidare l'argomento sul parametro 'Property'. L'argomento è null o vuoto. Fornire un
argomento che non sia null o vuoto ed eseguire di nuovo il comando.
In riga:4 car:82
+ ... uter\c$\users\*.* -Include *.*  -Force | Where-Object $_.Name -ne "Ad ...
+                                                           ~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Where-Object], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WhereObjectCommand

Where-Object : Impossibile convalidare l'argomento sul parametro 'Property'. L'argomento è null o vuoto. Fornire un
argomento che non sia null o vuoto ed eseguire di nuovo il comando.
In riga:4 car:82
+ ... uter\c$\users\*.* -Include *.*  -Force | Where-Object $_.Name -ne "Ad ...
+                                                           ~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Where-Object], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WhereObjectCommand
```

if I run the single command on a pc it works correctly

```
{Get–ChildItem –Path c:\users\*.* –Include *.*  –Force | Where-Object $_.Name -notmatch "Administrator" | Remove-Item -Force -Recurse
```

Comment: This may help [https://adamtheautomator.com/powershell-delete-user-profile/](https://adamtheautomator.com/powershell-delete-user-profile/)

Comment: doing so by UNC paths is probably very slow - use powerShellRemoting. furthermore it is not a good idea to delete userProfiles this way, u need to cleanup the registry also ... take a look at olafs link - this looks better :-)